# What do you call the container that looks like a ‘Pringles bottle’?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, terminology

I don't need to eat that Pringles. I need the name of the bottle that contains them, i.e. which is long, doesn't need to be round, empty inside and light-weight.

What do you call such a thing in English? What should I Google if I want to find such a container?

[image]

[[Source of the picture]](https://www.google.com/search?newwindow=1&site=&tbm=isch&q=pringles)

Comment: And I guess "bottle" is not correct way to call this thing. But I couldn't think of any other word so I used it.

Comment: Are you trying to think of the word [_tube_](http://beta.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tube)? Or perhaps [_canister_](http://beta.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/canister)? Or [_cylinder_](http://beta.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cylinder)?

Comment: I have edited your question. (Please see if it is OK) Why not use ***Pringles container***? It is unique and is close to a proper noun.

Comment: I think most answers misunderstand this question.  In my read, it is not, "What is the thing Pringles come in called?", but rather "What is the generic name for the *type* of container used for Pringles?"

Comment: But if it's ajar, does that mean the lid is off? :)

Comment: In the US it's usually called a "Pringles can".  But "tube" or "canister" would work.  Not a "box", since a "box" is not round.

Comment: And note that a long cardboard cylinder with caps at both ends is called a "mailing tube".  Typically used to hold charts and photographs for transport.

Comment: Hat boxes are round.

Comment: @VinceO'Sullivan - And when was the last time you saw a hat box?

Comment: slightly off topic... http://www.instructables.com/id/The-amazing-pringles-tube-Stirling-engine/

Comment: @user42459 wouldn't this question belong on ELL.SE?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

As Sven Yargs suggests, you eat a *can* of Pringles, or a *tube* of Pringles.

Bottle is definitely not a suitable word here. A bottle is something that has a narrow opening, and would typically be used to contain fluid.

> A glass or plastic container with a narrow neck, used for storing drinks or other liquids: he opened the bottle of beer

[Oxford dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/bottle)

Comment: Pringles [refers to them as "cans"](https://www.pringles.com/us/products.html), not "tubes" ([UK too](https://www.pringles.com/uk/products.html)).

Comment: @JasonC I originally just put 'can', but I realised I wouldn't consider 'tube' to be out of place, whereas if I said 'tin' I would probably correct myself.

Comment: @JessicaB TBH it doesn't even matter what they're in, they're usually gone before I know what happened. :(

Comment: @JasonC you're right. What are the Pringles in? No, not in a can - they're in me!

Comment: Tiny nitpick: do a Google Image Search for "Nalgene bottle." Not all bottles have narrow openings. If somebody made a plastic container in the exact shape of a Pringles can, but for carrying water, I'd call it a bottle. In this case it is the contents/purpose/material of the container that govern the name, not the shape. Less tiny notpick: It's also interesting that the same Oxford dictionary you quoted specifies that a "can" is made out of metal. Which makes the cardboard Pringles container I previously also called a can... more accurately, a tube.

Comment: @The111 A thing that shape for carrying water I would not call a bottle. It would be a flask, or a beaker (and found in a science lab). A google search suggests the lining of the cardboard is aluminium. But I think the thing here is that the name is not part of a general pattern because it's a pretty unique object. About the only other instance of this container I can think of is own-brand versions of Pringles.

Comment: @JasonC To be fair, I didn't say the Pringles were in a can, I said you eat them by the can ;)

Comment: https://goo.gl/qmNEN2 There is virtually no mention of Nalgene flask or Nalgene beaker compared to the ubiquitous Nalgene bottle. And maybe one other common thing shaped like Pringles tube is a tennis ball container, which I admit is called a can sometimes, but I think tube is better. Although admittedly Trends shows that can is much more common in both cases. ;-)

Comment: @The111 That's probably just a holdover from the phrase "water bottle" and I'd look at it more as an quirk rather than something that redefines "bottle". In any case it's a separate topic from cans and Pringles.

Comment: Might consider noting that canister also applies.

Comment: In lab terminology, a bottle is any *narrowed* mouth container, not, necessarily, an objectively narrow mouth. The Nalgene bottles began life as lab eq, so the name came from that, actually.

Answer (score 14):

Although that particular object is most often described as a *can of Pringles*, I'm going to go out on a limb and argue that this shape is more often called a *cylinder*.

A *can* is generally short, may be squat, and is usually made of metal. A *cylinder* is long and narrow with no default construction material assumed.

If you wanted Pringles, *can* is the right word. If you want a generic container like the one shown, *cylinder* will work better. As choster mentions below, a *canister* is often used for a cylinder that is used for food storage.

And also, this is sometimes called a **sleeve of Pringles**. You can google it; here's an example from [QuickMeme](http://www.quickmeme.com/meme/358w5b).

Comment: For what it's worth the bottom of a Pringles can is metal, and the inside is a metalicized paper.  Can is definitely the right word for Pringles.

Comment: +1 for *sleeve*, but I would suggest *canister* for cylinders used for food storage, as I think for most people, *can* is is very strongly associated with the [steel "tin" can](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tin_can).

Comment: @choster I agree with your assessment. I can edit mine, unless you want to post that as an answer too?

Comment: @KitZ.Fox I won't be posting an answer of my own.

Comment: Note that **cylinder** can just as accurately be used to refer to a shape with a radius exceeding its height.

Comment: @choster I've never heard the Pringles container called anything but a "can" (in US English).

Comment: I've called them cans myself, but have to admit that Oxford dictionary says cans are made of metal. ;-) I think the tube gives the illusion of metal, which lends itself to the name can. Tennis ball tubes, which are plastic, are less likely to be called cans I think (although they still are sometimes, as a quick Google search will show).

Comment: @Joe I believe so.

Answer (score 10):

The answer to your question is "**can**." (Thanks Mary-Lou.)

Here are two of many answers I got when I Googled, **"other uses for Pringles cans"**:

**22 Outstanding Ways to Re-use Pringles Cans:**

http://www.chasinggreen.org/article/22-outstanding-ways-re-use-pringles-cans/

**Pringles-Can Mods:**

http://walyou.com/pringles-can-mods/

There are dozens of others. The use of a Pringles can as an antenna is my favorite. Have fun!

Comment: Well I shan't be calling them *cans*. *Cans* are made of metal. As far as I'm concerned they are *tubes*.

Comment: If you enter a so-called "convenience store" in the U. S. and ask for a "Tube of Pringles," be prepared for a few giggles from those around you, *unless you happen to have a gorgeous British accent,* in which case you'll receive admiring smiles instead. **:-)** **Of course they are tubes!** But they are *called* **"cans of Pringles."**

Comment: Do they still 'ask for things' in American shops? The only time I 'ask' is if I can't find what I want. Otherwise I just grab it off the shelf.  We have come a long way since my uncle in his grocery shop would pour some rice onto a flat sheet of paper and wrap it for the customer - circa 1951.And he didn't have sticky tape either. I would think he tied it with string! I may have got that wrong. With things like rice and tea I think he first made the sheet of paper into a cone and poured the rice/tea in. All skills he would have learned as a grocer's apprentice circa 1925.

Comment: Hahahaha! I fear I am showing my age. But yes, I do still ask for things in shops rather than wandering the aisles hoping to find what I need. My gray hair usually earns me a *little* respect, so no one ever says to me, "The Pringles are on the *'Chips aisle,'* you idiot!"

Comment: ...And you do know that Pringles are made from a starchy wet potato mash and then pressed into wavy semi-flat round forms to loosely resemble an actual potato chip, right? Every single Pringle is exactly the same so that they stack neatly in the ***can*** and don't get broken in transit. Otherwise, they bear no resemblance to proper "chips" whatsoever, on either side of the pond!

Comment: An antiquarian bookseller in the United States recently sent me a book by Priority Mail (not the snail-paced "book rate") that he had carefully wrapped in paper, then padded with thin plastic foam, then placed in an oversized flat box in which he had put padding around all sides of the folio-sized book before mailing to ensure that it arrived in perfect condition. I owed him about $19 for postage but sent him a check for $35 and a hand-written thank you note from me and my wife for being a ***genuine bookseller in the best traditions of the trade*** and not just a "vendor of books."

Comment: @WS2 The Pringles can is composed in part of metal.

Comment: @Casey As is the case with some people's limbs. It doesn't mean they are made of metal though.

Comment: @WS2 Start typing "how many Pringles" into Google and very likely the first suggested completion will be "in a **can**" (emphasis added). It's possible that it's localized and different in British English places, but in American English, the only word is "can". [The Pringles website](https://www.pringles.com/us/products.html) itself calls them "cans". Connotations of metal notwithstanding, "can" is both the *de facto*  and official word for the container.

Comment: @ToddWilcox I did so, and here in the UK, the suggested completion was "in a tube"!  As you say, the Pringles website does call them cans, but the normal, day-to-day term for them in the UK are "tubes".

Comment: Interesting. Pringles all over the underground? ;-)

Comment: In English English, a can has to be made of metal. But don't you touch my Pringles!! They're mine! Hands off!

Answer (score 7):

There are several options, but this is best called a **canister.**

> A usually cylindrical storage container, especially:
>   a. A box or can of thin metal or plastic used for holding dry foodstuffs or cooking ingredients, such as flour or sugar.
>   -http://www.thefreedictionary.com/canister

It's a bit more descriptive than *can,* which is arguably correct, but which more often describes a can such as canned soup or other wet materials comes in, made of heavier material.  Consider also that it's perfectly possible to ask for a "cardboard canister," while a "cardboard can" sounds like a contradiction in terms.

This is not to say you would typically ask for a "canister of Pringles," but rather if you wanted to identify the container independent of the contents, you'd be more likely to get what you wanted with "canister" than "can."

Answer (score 3):

In  the Uk the trade name for this packaging product is ''Little John Drum''
They come in a vast variety of sizes.  I do not know the actual manufacturer's name, but that title would be a start for a web search.

Comment: I'm in the UK, and I've never heard of that. I would guess it's something you'd only know if you were in the packaging industry.

Answer (score 3):

In the England the following applies for container names:

- If it has a narrow neck, it is a *bottle*.
- If glass or ceramic, with an opening the full width of the bottle (or almost), use *jar*.
- If it is made of metal, and cannot be reclosed, it is a *tin* or *can*.
- If it metal and can be reclosed, it is a *tin*.
- If it is made of paper or cardboard, use *box* or *carton* - unless it is round, and sturdy - then you may use *drum* or *tube* if it qualifies.
- If it is short, say less than one and a half times as high as it is wide, and round, use *drum* or *tub*.
- If it is round, and longer than it is wide, you may use *tube*. If it is not round, and is much longer, you may also use tube.
- If it is not round, use *tub*.
- If all else fails, *container* will usually do.

In England we don't use *can* unless the material is metallic. So the pringles container would usually be called a *tube*, but could be a *tub*, *carton*, *container* or *packet*. They short ones could also be called *drums*.

The reason for all these variants is unimportant historical accidents. The distinction between tins and cans for example is because the English word was *tin*, and *can* is an Americanism, but *canned drinks* brought the word *can* to England, hence *cans* are primarily drinks tins, which brings the connotation that they usually cannot be reclosed.

Comment: A wonderfully comprehensive list! AsvPringles containers are made of card, I would call it a 'drum', as you say.  Or a tube, which feels like a more modern word.

Answer (score 0):

In the northeastern USA we would refer to a can or stack of Pringles or, if it's a plastic container, a tub of Pringles.  Other food containers which bear the same shape are canisters (cylindrical boxes with a cardboard or plastic lid like for oatmeal), jars (glass or clear palstic with a twist on lid like for jam and peanut butter),cartons (generally cardboard or waxed cardboard, rectangular with a flat or pointed top as for milk or eggs) or tubs (colored plastic with a snap on lid like for margarine or whipped cream).  Cans are almost exclusively one use metal containers which, once opened, cannot be resealed.  Perhaps Pringles refer to their packaging as a can because of the aluminum lining of the vacuum packed canister much like a coffee can which, once the pull top is opened can't be actually resealed but has a plastic lid for after opening.

Answer (score -3):

Since a bottle is made out of glass (or plastic) a glass container or plastic canister with the shape of a can of Pringles would be called a "jar".